# How to access values of Input in a List

Tags: javascript, html

For my Project I need to have a site, which can generate a custom amount of Inputs, which will become buttons in another page.

And I need the values for the Input in order to Label the Buttons correctly.

**HTML**

```html
<h2>settings:</h2>

<p>Add Amount of Checks:</p>
<input id="NumOfButtons"
       name="NumOfButtons"
       pattern=""
       size="30"
       spellcheck="false"
       title="Amount of Checks"
       value="">

<script>

    let input = document.getElementById("NumOfButtons");
    let listTA = new Array;
    
    input.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
        
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("NumOfButtons").value);
            listTA = new Array(x);
            

            for (let i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
                var textarea = document.createElement("input");
                textarea.name = "input";
                textarea.maxLength = "100";
                textarea.id = "TextAreaID"
                listTA[i] = textarea;
                document.getElementById("Buttons").appendChild(textarea);
            }

           
        }
    });
                
</script>

<div id="Buttons">
    <br />
    <button onclick="sendDataAndGoToKontrolle()">save & continue</button>
    <p>Reset F5</p>
</div>

<script>
    function sendDataAndGoToKontrolle() {
        var filtered;
        if (listTA != null) {
            let x = new Array;
            for (let i = 0; i < listTA.length; ++i) x[i] = listTA[i].document.getElementById("TextAreaID").value;

            if (!(x.length === 0)) {
                for (let i = 0; i < x.length; ++i) {
                    if (x[i] === null) {
                        var filtered = x.filter(function (el) { return el != null; });
                        console.log("TextAreas filtered!")
                    } else console.log("Nothing to filter!")
                }
            } else console.log("Nothin written in TextAreas!");  
        } else console.log("No TextArea created!");

        if (!(filtered === null)) {
            //Send Prüfungen to Controller
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("NewIDSettingsPage")",
                type: "GET",
                data: { Prüfungen: filtered },
                success: function () {
                    console.log("Successfully sent!");
                    //window.location.href = '/home/NewIDSettingsPage';
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText;
                    console.log("ERROR: " + errorMessage);}});
        } else console.log("ERROR");
    }
</script>
```

The result should be a list/Array of **string**(values of the Inputs).

If you need any further information, please write a Comment and I will look to reply quickly.

Comment: Oh yeah I often mistake them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not give all the input elements the same id. `textarea.id = "TextAreaID"` is wrong.

If you want to group the inputs together you should set the class:

```
textarea.className = "TextAreaClass"
```

Or if you want to give each one an id, append `i` to the id to make it unique:

```
textarea.id = "TextAreaID"+i;
```

When trying to get the values of your inputs you have the following:

```
 x[i] = listTA[i].document.getElementById("TextAreaID").value;
```

Which doesn't make a lot of sense. What you should probably be doing is:

```
 x[i] = listTA[i].value;
```

Because you have stored the element in the array, you don't need to get the element from the document.